# 'ToastProvider' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a "not-too-old" React application that uses Typescript.
After installing the dependencies, some of the packages started throwing errors which so far I have been resolving. but I can't seem to figure out how to resolve the issue with react-toast-notification.

This is the codeblock that is throwing the error

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <ApolloHooksProvider client={client}>
      <AppContextProvider>
        <ToastProvider placement="top-right">
          <IdleApp />
        </ToastProvider>
      </AppContextProvider>
    </ApolloHooksProvider>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is the error

```
'ToastProvider' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<ToastProviderProps, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<ToastProviderProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<ToastProviderProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type
```

Kindly help nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: Looks like it's no longer maintained: https://github.com/jossmac/react-toast-notifications

Comment: Thank you, I've seen this but he's doing the exact thing I've done that is throwing the error. I'm hoping I could get help as to how to convert the <ToastProvider> to a JSX Element.

Comment: If you hover over `ToastProvider `, what does it say? The error message is said to looking for a jsx element, so your provider's return type should be `: JSX.Element`